# JDBC connection

Tags: java, jdbc

Hi folks 
I am new to java programming.Can anyone suggest me some good reading for JDBC connection.
I have to connect my java program to a database.
Also while searching on net i found the following statement a bit confusing

```
1)Connection dbConnection=DriverManager.getConnection(url,”loginName”,”Password”)

2)Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
```

In the second statement "createStatement" is a method of "Interface Connection".

How can i call a method of an interface??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ajay,
JDBC is an API (Standard) published by Sun (now Oracle :-( )..

When you code, you use the API to write the code based in interfaces (NOTE: Open javadoc and see... JDBC is a collection of interfaces.. java.sql.* package)

When you want to run the application, you have to use an implementation provided by the Database vendor...
All DB vendors that provide JDBC support have to provide this implementation. classes12.jar or ojdbc14.jar etc... Open that jar file in zip utility and you can see the classes java.sql.Interface and so on...

those are the concrete classes that implement the interfaces that you asked about in your question....

SO you are actually using a concrete class. Learn about inheritance in java.

these may help you

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/overview-141217.html

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html

http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Database/JDBC20Intro/JDBC20.html

http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/jdbc.shtml [good hands on tutorial]

hope this helps...

Thanks.

Comment: By the way Ajay, look at the initial java statements before the code that you provided... Class.forName("SQL_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME");

Comment: Thanx Ayusman.That means the Interafce "Connection" and "statement" are implemented by Db vendors.I dint know that and that was the reason for my confusiion.

Comment: That's right Ajay, Sun (now oracle) provides the spec or API as we call it as a set of interfaces... the vendor takes the API, writes implementations for those because only they have the clear knowledge of how to implement them for their database and provide us the type 4 driver. You have to use the driver to connect to the DB and perform various operations like creating connections, executing SQL statements and so on and so forth. java.sql.* is a great example of design by interface. I like to call it a funnel out approach in contrast to using Abstract classes (funnel in approach) :-)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the official tutorial link provided by hilal, I'll explain how JDBC works.

JDBC is a standard. It defines a set of interfaces. Then each JDBC driver - that is, a concrete implementation for a particular database, has to follow exactly these interfaces.

Then the driver registers itself in the driver manager (previously you had to do this with `Class.forName(..)`, and when you call `DriverManager.getConnection(..)`, the proper driver is chosen based on the passed url, and it instantiates a connection.

Now about that connection, and your last question - if you output `connection.getClass()` you will get `com.mysql.driver.ConnectionImpl` (for example). This means that the jdbc driver has provided an implementation of the `Connection` interface, but you don't need to be aware of the classes of each driver - you only need to know the JDBC interfaces.

That said, I think you should read a bit more not only about JDBC, but about interfaces and polymorphism in general. *You refer to the object by the interface, but the object is always an instance of a concrete class that implements the interface.*

Answer (score 1):

The JDBC api which is defined by the Oracle (Initially by Sun Microsystems) - - A Set of Interfaces should be implemented by the particular JDBC Vendor.

Say for example, if you are using MySql Driver, then the MySql people has to implement all the interfaces that are defined by the Oracle (Sun initially).

Answer (score -1):

It is so so simple that you can start [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html) and simple example [here](http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/Jdbc-connection.shtml)

Comment: I had one more question.How can i call a method of an interface??

Comment: This question is not related to jdbc you should start with java interface tutorial. create a class that implement this interface and implement the method in that class and call just like a simple class method

Comment: @AjaySingh you do not call a method of an interface. When you use the JDBC driver, it automatically provides you a reference to the IMPLEMENTATION of the interface writen by the database vendor. So you actually are invoking methods on an object of the class that implements the interface. So the jdbc type 4 driver from oracle will have a concrete class called statement that implements the java.sql.Statement interface. Hope you got it by now.

Comment: Downvoted because pasting links is not the answer, should be a comment instead.